# Alerts with sound

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4

The script below identifies a doji candle and changes it to a yellow colour and works.
What command line would trigger a sound alert in TV on a specific timeframe like 5 mins?
In TV there are global alert function they have limited choices based on measurements.e.g. crossing up , crossing down, less than , greater than
Is there a way to code a sound alert?
This is the code:
//@version=3
//Doji signals :D

study(title = "Doji signals")

Precision = input(0.15, minval=0.0001, title="Doji's Max Body size")
barcolor(abs(open - close) <= (high - low) * Precision ? yellow : na)

doji=(abs(open - close) <= (high - low) * Precision ? 1:0)
plot (doji)

alertcondition(doji, title='DDD', message='DBD')

Answer (score 0):

You can turn sounds on in your alert setup window =) [image: Picture@@@]

Comment: Thank you. Ok great. What code extra code do. I need to get the alert triggered? How do I code ( alertcondition(doji, title='DDD', message='DBD')) to get the condition to work the condition in the above picture you posted?

Comment: Can one use plot_color0 = yellow to trigger a alert?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you can't. Been searching this question for some time now.
The best I can figure to do so far is to approximate the script's alert condition with the logic available in TV's alert dialog.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).